# Reading messages from rabbitMQ queue at an interval is not working

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

What I am trying to achieve is to read messages from a RabbitMQ queue every 15 minutes. From the documentation, I could see that I can use the "receiveTimeout" method to set the interval.

> **Polling Consumer**
>
> The AmqpTemplate itself can be used for polled Message reception. By default, if no message is
> available, null is returned immediately. There is no blocking. Starting with version 1.5, you can set
> a receiveTimeout, in milliseconds, and the receive methods block for up to that long, waiting for a
> message.

But I tried implementing it with sprint integration, the receiveTimeout is not working as I expected.

My test code is given below.

```
@Bean
    Queue createMessageQueue() {
        return new Queue(RetryQueue, false);
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer QueueMessageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(
                connectionFactory);
        messageListenerContainer.setQueueNames(RetryQueue);
        messageListenerContainer.setReceiveTimeout(900000);
        return messageListenerContainer;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter inboundQueueChannelAdapter(
            @Qualifier("QueueMessageListenerContainer") AbstractMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer) {
        final AmqpInboundChannelAdapter amqpInboundChannelAdapter = new AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(
                messageListenerContainer);
        amqpInboundChannelAdapter.setOutputChannelName("channelRequestFromQueue");
        return amqpInboundChannelAdapter;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "channelRequestFromQueue")
    public void activatorRequestFromQueue(Message<String> message) {
        System.out.println("Message: " + message.getPayload() + ", recieved at: " + LocalDateTime.now());
    }
```

I am getting the payload logged in the console in near real-time.
Can anyone help? How much time the consumer will be active once it starts?

**UPDATE**

IntegrationFlow I used to retrieve messages from queue at an interval,

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundIntegrationFlowPaymentRetry() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Amqp.inboundPolledAdapter(connectionFactory, RetryQueue),
                        e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(20_000).maxMessagesPerPoll(-1)).autoStartup(true))
                .handle(message -> {
                    channelRequestFromQueue()
                            .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.getPayload()).copyHeaders(message.getHeaders())
                                    .setHeader(IntegrationConstants.QUEUED_MESSAGE, message).build());
                }).get();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Polling Consumer` documentation is from the Spring AMQP documentation about the `RabbitTemplate, and has nothing to do with the listener container, or Spring Integration.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#polling-consumer

Spring integration's adapter is message-driven and you will get messages whenever they are available.

To get messages on-demand, you need to call the `RabbitTemplate` on whatever interval you want.

Comment: You can also use this if you are in Spring Integration already: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/amqp.html#polled-inbound-channel-adapter

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thanks. I was looking for something like this. But when I tried, individual messages are fetched in the specified interval. But what I need is, I want to fetch all the available messages when a queue is polled. Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: Set `maxMessagesPerPoll` on the poller; it defaults to 1, -1 means keep fetching until there are no more. `Pollers.fixedDelay(1_000).maxMessagesPerPoll(-1)`.

Comment: Note that you should use a transactional poller if you want to avoid losing message loss; by default, the message is acknowledged after it is fetched.

Comment: @GaryRussell I need to post the already fetched message if some certain scenarios. I used 
StaticMessageHeaderAccessor.getAcknowledgmentCallback(queuedMessage).acknowledge(Status.REQUEUE);
 to requeue the message. but the problem here is, the requeued messages are immediately picked up by the poller. Hence it is going in an infinite loop. Can you please advise? The poller code snippet is added in the question for your reference.

Comment: That's how RabbitMQ works, rejected messages (with requeue) are put back on the head of the queue; if you want it to go to a different queue, or to the tail, you have to republish it yourself.

Comment: Republishing is working. but the polling delay doesn't have an effect in the above-mentioned scenario. the message is getting published before the inbound adapter goes to sleep after reading that message. that's the issue I want to solve. i don't want to process the same message in a single read cycle of the amqpInboundChannelAdapter. Is there a way to block this?

Comment: You can set up another queue with a TTL, configured to send the message (via dead-letter configuration) back to the original queue after the TTL expires. But this is a new question; if you need help with it, start a new queustion.

Comment: @GaryRussell i have created a new question. Can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69401412/republishing-message-into-rabbitmq-queue-creates-an-infinite-loop